# Missing Xapian library in Doxygen build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, doxygen, xapian

I am attempting to build Doxygen using VS2013.  I have downloaded the project from GitHub and I have installed Flex and Bison.  When I attempt to build, it fails due to reference to Xapian header files that it cannot find/open.  Xapian was not listed as a prereq for this so I don't know if I need to install something else of if it is already a part of the Doxygen package and I need to correct something in VS2013 to resolve the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Xapian is only needed for the external search engine (doxysearch targets).

Next to building Xapian from source you can also download prebuild xapian libraries for Windows from here: http://ftp.stack.nl/pub/users/dimitri/xapian_doxygen_win.zip

Comment: Do I need doxysearch to run doxygen?  Or can I generate the code documentation without the search?

Comment: Doxysearch (and Xapian) is not required for doxygen. Doxygen offers 7 ways to search through the output as you can read here: http://www.doxygen.org/manual/searching.html. Only the 3rd option requires Xapian.

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen supports a range of search options, one of which depends on Xapian, but unfortunately this dependency doesn't seem to be documented in the installation notes. There are [instructions for building Xapian on Windows](http://www.flax.co.uk/xapian_binaries), which also include pre-built binaries, although as I'm not a Windows user I can't tell you exactly which archives you'll need to get things working. `xapian.h` is in the `xapian-core` source code (it's the main Xapian header file, used when compiling any code that uses Xapian for search features).

If you run into problems building or installing Xapian on Windows, I'd suggest posting to the [xapian-discuss](http://lists.xapian.org/mailman/listinfo/xapian-discuss) mailing list. (The person who was maintaining the Windows build system is stepping down, but hopefully someone will be able to help out.)